# Connect to subversion using SVN API with C++-Builder

Tags: c++, svn, c++builder

I try to connect my application to a subversion server using the Embarcadero RadStudio XE6 C++-Builder.
I tried some code from the file minimal_client.c
I can compile but cannot link it because of the missing SVN.LIB. I cannot find that file anywhere. I recieved the api files using svn-win32-1.8.11-ap24_dev.zip (http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.8.11/apache24/). Does anyone know, where to find that file or is it possible to link it without svn.lib, maybe by using a dll?

Comment: I think you should look for libsvn.*

Comment: That didn't work. The linker is still looking for SVN.LIB

Comment: Do you have any svn.lib or libsvn.lib on your disk?

Comment: I have libsvn_client-1.lib, svn_client-1.lib and some others (libsvn_*-1.lib, svn_*-1.lib) on my disk.

Comment: I think you shoild try to add to your project libsvn-client-1.lib it should work.

Comment: I tried to add libsvn_client-1.lib or svn_client-1.lib or both but the linker still looked for svn.lib